# Presenting Modal ViewController from (Table)ViewController inside a NavigationController inside a TabBarController

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch, uinavigationcontroller, uitabbarcontroller, modalviewcontroller

When I try presenting the modal controller right from the table view controller (could be a normal view controller as well), it appears behind the tab bar and looks quite ugly as I'm using a blur effect on it. I am using a navigation controller because I need to have a bar at the top and, after research, found that's the best way to do it.

I have found that doing something like:

`self.parent?.parent?.present(ModelViewController(), animated: true, completion: nil)`

when wanting to present the modal controller works. However, I imagine this isn't very safe. What is the correct way of doing this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In order for the ModalViewController to present in front of the tab bar, its `modalPresentationStyle` has to be set to `overFullScreen`. So for instance when initializing the ModalViewController:

`self.modalPresentationStyle = .overFullScreen` (Swift 3 syntax)